# Issue with google analytics API regarding number of rows

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am new to Google analytic, I have a dashboard and want to export data from googleanalytics dashboard. My problem is as soon as increase the time frame in the dashboard, no. of rows decreasing how is it possible. Even if the rows are being grouped together number of rows should not decrease when the time frame is increased. Can anybody help me on this ??